# Error while uploading .xlsx file using ExcelDataReader

Tags: asp.net-mvc, excel, iis, access-denied, exceldatareader

I am working on asp.net MVC project.

I use [ExcelDataReader](https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader) component to read excel file records.

Now when I published my project to server and upload a .xlsx file with uploader I get below mentioned exception message. There are no errors with local deployment but server.

> Access to the path '\Microsoft Corporation\Internet Information
>   Services\7.5.7600.16385' is denied.

and code where I am getting error is:

```
if (personsFile.FileExtension == ".xls")
{
     Stream st = new MemoryStream(personsFile.FileArray);
     reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(st);
}
else if (personsFile.FileExtension == ".xlsx")
{
     Stream st = new MemoryStream(personsFile.FileArray);
     //exception occured on under line
     reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(st);
}
```

But when I upload a .xls file, I dont have any error.

How to resolve issue with .xlsx extenstion?

Comment: What is data type and value of personsFile?

Comment: @PankajKapare personsFile is a object that has 2 property , one, FileExtension that is string  and two, FileArray that is byte array

Comment: Have you tried CreateReader or CreateBinaryReader instead of CreateOpenXmlReader?

Comment: @PankajKapare yes, and throw exception. and if you see the example of component creator will see that use CreateOpenXmlReader for xlsx extenstion. furthermore i don't have error in my local

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely due to ExcelDataReader 2.x extracting the xlsx archive to %TEMP% before processing it. The current pre-alpha of 3.0 no longer does this. See https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader/releases.